# Wicket(1.3.7) HeaderContributor.forJavascript path

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to add a javascript reference using this code :

`ResourceReference js; 
js = JavascriptResourceReference("/assets/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js");

add(HeaderContributor.forJavaScript(js));`

The problem is wicket puts the path like this :
`src="resources/org.apache.wicket.Application//assets/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js"`

and I want to be just

`src="assets/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js"`

but in its documentation it is specified so :

`-> Starts with http:// or https:// for an external reference.
-> Starts with "/" for an absolute reference that Wicket will not rewrite.
-> Starts with anything else, which Wicket will automatically prepend to make relative to the context root of your web-app.`

Answer (score 0):

I used this syntax, and it worked :

`add(HeaderContributor.forJavaScript("/assets/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js"));`